# Kafka - Get Ip address or hostnames connected to the cluster

Tags: logging, kafka

I have a test Kafka Cluster in AWS MSK with three brokers. I'd like to know how to get information about who is connecting to the cluster either to produce or consume messages.

For instance, MSSQL Server logs successful connections:

```
Login succeeded for user 'sa'. Connection made using SQL Server authentication. [CLIENT: 192.XX.X.XX]
```

Is there a way in Kafka to know who is connecting and from where?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Out of the box...

Producers - not possible

Consumers - use `kafka-consumer-groups --describe` over all group IDs and parse the output to get client ids.

---

This does not preclude you from adding distributed tracing solutions that can track Kafka client server connections (and see what topics they interact with)

Comment: Thank you! - any particular tracing solution you'd recommend?

Comment: Start here - https://www.confluent.io/blog/importance-of-distributed-tracing-for-apache-kafka-based-applications/